# Windows user name an password authentication for account not currently logged in

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2005

I can access the current Windows user, but I want to give an admin the ability to enter an alternate username and password for a different Windows Active Directory Account without having to logoff and log back in. Once the account is authenticated, I need to use it in a connection string to sql server. I know I could do this for a SQL Server login, but this is Windows Authentication only.

It was installed with ClickOnce. Is there an .exe file on the user's machine?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of methods you could use:

1. **Change the current user.** This can be done in number of ways. Shift+right clicking the EXE and doing a Run As... is the easiest.
2. **Change the SQL string used to connect to database.** This is pretty straight forward,  but a bit ugly. Instead of using integrated security (or whatever you are using) in your connection string, you can manually specify the user and password, based on what they enter into your user logon screen.

Do you need them to be able to switch while the program is running?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I've not seen any situations that "run as" doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to change the user that the current thread is running as (impersonation).

[Here is an article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/UserImpersonationInNET.aspx) that describes one way to approach this.